# Am getting status code 401 when access Keycloak users list even after adding realm-management roles

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

Am running keycloak version 10.0.2. I have set up a new Realm [Screenshot for creation of realm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeHKL.png)

I have also created created a client called demo-app [Screenshot for creation of client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7FLH.png)

I went a head and created user. On role mapping tab i assigned two realm-management role one view-realm and the other view-users [screenshot for realm-management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuLpd.png)

After those configurations i tried this curl request to obtain access key

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/test realm/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=demo-app' \
--data-urlencode 'username=benmuuo' \
--data-urlencode 'password=1234' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password'
```

after getting the access token i did this request

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/admin/realms/test realm/users' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJROWZUcUtwWm9vZWRCSFZObmNZb19EUGRyc09BejhlMzMzZjhOMjJCRVBvIn0.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.drQwz61b1f6B7E2e5g5k0poDPucEav4yd5FIN7kPjbl2Kgo8w96i9M98htcBkFkk6_EcWGx7U5H4TgAng4x_VVrCC8KgtIM_Jbmz0h_7bx_4LCkCcxmka-zuxBm4BKjF42XHOApKmL26dAnRbFgckp3SZ8v14Xz77Va0tPcH4R_Ap0VgkD0X3kj5rbInsvtrBDgQyinFSPZxe9fzW9ZybkQ4UmN_Plj6zbDwOmPbA1vOEuhPRmddgM5TfDr46bmeiuw6jrqD-1IA6glkt4H2P9ebjFWVHePLw9eyE8F0onRqOVajQgN60d2hNSSi-FsHHr-DoQG5mEQx797yrr4TVQ'
```

this is when am getting the 401 error

```
 {
    "error": "HTTP 401 Unauthorized"
}
```

What could be causing the issue cause i don't get it.

Comment: `test realm` or `test realms`?

Comment: Sorry about that its test realm let me update the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Keycloak has problems with realms that have names containing non URL-friendly characters (such as a space). You can see https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-7844 and https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/5375#issuecomment-405343026 for more details.

The only viable solution (for now, that is Keycloak 11.0.2-) is to forbid the creation of such realms, for example by changing the theme to have any validation of the realm names in the input fields.

Try to change the realm name to `test-realm` and you can use `Test Realm` as a realm display name.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should do this request with admin(master) profile

```
curl --location --request POST 
'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=admin-cli' \
--data-urlencode 'username=admin' \
--data-urlencode 'password=admin' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password'
```

After getting the access token, try this request

```
curl --location --request GET 
'http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/test realm/users' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer your-access-token
```

Comment: Yeah this work but this is not exactly what i was looking for. My understanding is real users should be able to view users under that realm thats why I mapped that user with view-users role.